# Missing functions in Table Library in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

When I run table.maxn() or table.getn() in Lua I get the errors below:

```
> table.maxn(a)
stdin:1: attempt to call a nil value (field 'maxn')
stack traceback:
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
> table.getn(a)
stdin:1: attempt to call a nil value (field 'getn')
stack traceback:
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

When I try to explore the contents of the table object I get the results below. It is almost as though some functions are missing from the library.

```
> for k,v in pairs(table) do
>> print (k)
>> end
remove
insert
move
sort
concat
unpack
pack
>
```

I am using Lua5.3 - from downloaded win32 binaries > Lua53.exe

I have confirmed that I did not alter / affect the table object in any way. The results above were obtained after restarting the Interpreter afresh.

What could the issue be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using lua 5.3 but:

- `table.getn` was deprecated in lua 5.1 ([ref](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#7.2))
- `table.maxn` was deprecated in lua 5.2 ([ref](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#8.2))

You need to write valid code for the version of lua you are targetting.

Comment: In that case they need to ensure that the online version of Programming In Lua either reflects the current situation or is removed - the samples in that doc include table.getn so they won't work.  I had to google the error message which ended up here with the answer

I know that there are newer versions of PIL, but they are chargeable.  I can't justify expenditure during initial evaluation. When initially evaluating a product, I expect all published examples to work, or to clearly indicate that they only apply to specific versions,

Examples on the website should ALWAYS work first time.

Comment: @grahamhanson "They" don't **need** to do anything. The online version of Programming in Lua is **explicitly** documented as being for the 5.0 version of lua on the [lua.org docs page](https://www.lua.org/docs.html): "The third edition is aimed at Lua 5.2. The first edition was aimed at Lua 5.0 and is [available online](https://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html); it is still largely relevant."